# How to read binary file with text header using stremreader in powershell?

Tags: powershell, binary, streamreader

I have a binary log file that has text headers describing the file. The headers are of the form:

```
FileName: <filename>
Datetime: <dateTime>
NumberOfLines: <nnn>
DataForm: l,l,d,d,d,d
DataBlock:
```

After that there goes a binary portion of the file:

```
ｳｩｮ・  ` 0  ｳｩｮﾟ?~・?ﾖｿﾌ>・・?Glfｳﾁﾒ>-~JUｯ羲ｿ濂・x・-$>;ﾉPｾ.・4ﾂﾇ岐・ｾ:)胥篩・tｼj~惞ｹ劔劔劒    ｳｩｯ   ` 0  ｳｩｯ?Gd$・ﾌ>・)
```

and so on...

The headers I can read and parse into variables using this:

```
$streamReader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::New($FullPath)
while (($currentLine = $streamReader.ReadLine()) -ne 'DataBlock: ') {
   $variableName, $variableValue = $currentLine -split ':'
   New-Variable -Name $variableName -Value $variableValue.Trim() -Force
}
```

Now to the binary block.
This binary portion is basically a CSV-like data structure. `DataForm` describes how long the fields are and what is data type for each field. `NumberOfLines` - how many lines there are.

So, I know how to read and parse the binary portion using:

```
[Byte[]] $FileByteArray = Get-Content $FullPath -Encoding Byte
```

and knowing the start position of the data block. For instance, the first field in the example above is 'l' which is 4 bytes for *UInt32* data type. Assuming my data block starts at byte 800, I can read it like this:

```
$byteArray = $FileByteArray[800..803]
[BitConverter]::ToUInt32($byteArray, 0)
```

and so on.

Now, the question.
I'd like to use my existing StreamReader that I used to parse headers to keep advancing through the file (not by line now, but by chunks of bytes) and read it as bytes. How do I do that?
If I can only read characters using StreamReader - what other methods I can use?
I don't want to read headers using StreamReader, calculating along the line the starting position of my data block through length of each line plus two bytes for new line symbols, and then read the whole file again through `[Byte[]] $FileByteArray = Get-Content $FullPath -Encoding Byte`

Comment: You can try using a [BinaryReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader) instead of a `StreamReader`. 
BinaryReader has methods for reading characters (`ReadChars()`) aswell as for reading bytes (`ReadBytes()`)

Comment: I don't see that it can read lines. Header can be conveniently parsed by reading lines.

Comment: Not lines, but characters you need to string together to form the lines. Then from certain point onwards you start reading bytes from the dame file